# Adding a row to an SQL CE database?

Tags: c#, sql, insert, sql-server-ce

I've been trying to add a row to my SQL CE & nothing works I've tried many things I found here at SO or in other websites by googling but to no avail.

Below if the code I have at the moment.

It compiles and executes with no problem, but nothing is added to the table and no exception is thrown.

Could anyone please provide a solution for this ?

```
string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.TestConnectionString;

            using (SqlCeConnection connect = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
            {
                connect.Open();

                string text = "UsernameTest";
                string pass = "PasswordTest";

                using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("insert into MyTable values (@Username, @Password)", connect))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Please do not comment about storing a password in plain text, this was just a test.

Comment: _Please do not comment about storing a password in plain text.._ Yes master!

Comment: I have a dataGridView bound with that specific table.

Comment: It is set to copy if newer already.